# mysql query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

Okay, so my mysql query syntax is returning this **error:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'read='yes' WHERE id='1'' at line 1
```

Here is the **query:**

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE newnotifications SET read='$read' WHERE id='$id'");
```

The variables are in the error. I honestly have no idea what is wrong in the syntax. I have even copied & pasted from another one I have that works and just filled in other values for what to `update`, `where` and `set`.

Comment: read is a reserved word (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to change the syntax to:$update = mysql_query("UPDATE newnotifications SET `read`='$read' WHERE id='$id'");

Comment: @jeff: Your comment got formatted oddly, maybe because of the backticks. I think that the answer below shows it better.

Answer (score 3):

Read is a reserved word,enclose it in backticks

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

```
SET `read`
```

Comment: ...again :/? Thanks for the link though, will check before posting next time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE newnotifications SET `read`='$read' WHERE id='$id'");
```